# Process builder: Update a case field by process builder rule criteria

Tags: apex, process-builder

I am trying to create a process  in Process builder to update a custom text field in Case object on below criteria.

1. Case description is not null  = false
   AND
2. Case description Ischanged = true
   OR
3. Case description IsNew() = true

I created a criteria for Executioning actions as Formula evaluates to true under criteria section with below formula. But this formula is giving syntax error.
Formula:
[Case].Description  !=NULL AND (IsChanged() OR IsNew())

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`[Case].Description !=NULL`

You need to use the [`ISBLANK()`](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions.htm&type=5) function to check for null/empty fields.

`AND (IsChanged() OR IsNew())`

If your process is running due to a record event, which appears to be the case, this is always true: the object was either changed or new, always. You don't need this criterion.

Comment: Thank you David. But I got error while running this formula. This process is running for updating a case record on the base of mentioned criteria.